# angular 6 webpack manual setup

Tags: angular, webpack

Just created very first time an Angular 6 application by using CLI.

There are tones of files, is this only the way (Angular-CLI) to create angular application or we can manually setup by using only the required items like Angular 6 and Webpack.

After learning the React and came back to Angular, I realize why react became more famous.

Any good article to setup angular 6 with webpack, please.

Answer (score -3):

It is advicable to use Angular Cli to build your project since it takes care of most of the complexities in your app.
You don't have to care about the most of the files. Only the folder required for the development is the app folder inside src. So don't panic with so much files believe me only few files are there for your purpose and rest are there to give to the service like complilation with refreshing and many more. 
And once you are ready to move your project to production then you will find out that there are only few files required and not all these files.
And of Course we can set the project manually but then you will miss most of the features provided by the Cli. So use this features instead of building from scratch.

Comment: This answer doesn't conform to the requirements of the question. Setting up Angular 6 using webpack manually was the question.